# Why global variable ofstream in header can't write files in C++?

Tags: c++, fstream

1.For example, there are `a.cpp, b.h, b.cpp b.h`

b.h:

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_B_H
#define UNTITLED_B_H
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class b {
    ofstream b_out; // here
public:
    explicit b();
    int b_write(const string &message);
};
#endif //UNTITLED_B_H
```

b.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"
b::b(){        
    b_out.open("test.txt");
}
int b::b_write(const string &message){
    b_out<<message;
}
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"
int main(){
    b *b_object = new b();
    b_object->b_write("hello happy b");
}
```

this code has no error and file is created.
but message is not printed.

However, bring ofstream definition code(//here marked) to b.cpp like below.

b.h:

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_B_H
#define UNTITLED_B_H
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class b {
public:
    explicit b();
    int b_write(const string &message);
};
#endif //UNTITLED_B_H
```

b.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"
ofstream b_out; //here
b::b(){
    b_out.open("test.txt");
}
int b::b_write(const string &message){
    b_out<<message;
}
```

in this case, message is printed well.

but I don't understand diff between them.

can anyone help me?

thank you!

Comment: In what sense it doesn't work? You get an error? The file is not created? The message is not written?

Comment: What do you mean by "code is not working", do you get an compilation error? Runtime error? What's the error message?

Comment: no error, and file is created. but message is not printed.

Comment: Try to flush after writing

Comment: @Robert Kock, It printed message well. It is mysterious to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create your instance of `b` on the heap

```cpp
b *b_object = new b();
```

That means you are responsible for deleting it when you're no longer using it

```cpp
b* b_object = new b();
/* use b_object here */
delete b_object;
```

Without the call to `delete`, destructor is not called, meaning destructor of `ofstream` is not called, which would call a flush on the stream, writing message to the file. When you created the `ofstream` instance as a global inside your `b.cpp`, the compiler was responsible for calling the destructor of it, which is why it worked.

Don't manage the memory by yourself, use a smart pointer

```cpp
#include <memory>

auto smart_ptr = std::make_unique<b>();
smart_ptr->b_write("hello happy b");
```

It will call the `delete` for you.

Better yet, there's really no reason why you should be allocating the memory on the heap, if you created your instance of `b` on the stack, the compiler would do everything for you, thanks to RAII.

```cpp
int main(){
    b b_object;
    b_object.b_write("hello happy b");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation!